# getting json exception with Retrofit version 2.0 and special character "-" and "_" in email address

Tags: android, retrofit2, special-characters

I'm having trouble passing in any email address with the character *-* or a *_* when a user tries to sign up.  Here is the retrofit definition:

```
@Headers(API_KEY)
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("signInUser")
Call<HttpResponseModel> signInUser(@Field(value ="userEmail", encoded = true) String userEmail,
                                   @Field("userId") String userId,
                                   @Field("userPasswordHash") String pwHash);
```

and my method call:

```
Call<HttpResponseModel> signInUser = retrofitApiInterface.signInUser(userEmail, userId, passWord);

    signInUser.enqueue(new Callback<HttpResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<HttpResponseModel> call, @NonNull Response<HttpResponseModel> response) {
           .....  //my implemenation

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<HttpResponseModel> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            listener.onFailure(); //exception gets thrown here
        }
    });
}
```

And the error message I'm getting is:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

For example, an email that is throwing the exception: I would use would be:  my-name@email.com.

It works fine if the email address is myname@email.com

Call values:

```
encodedNames = {Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList@12120}  size = 3
0 = "userEmail"
1 = "userId"
2 = "userPasswordHash"
encodedValues = {Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList@12121}  size = 3
0 = "my-name%40email.com"
1 = ""
2 = "mypassword"
```

Comment: You are getting that error message because API returns JSONArray but you're expecting JSONObject in client side. Are you sure that API returns JSONObject, not JSONArray?  Why do you want to use `encoded = true`? Did you try without `encoded = true`? If possible, please share the sample JSON response from the server.

Comment: @Shashanth yes, I tried it without the encoded = true first.  I can't give you a server response, because the process never gets that far.  It happens before the request is sent to the server.

Comment: Test it with Postman client and confirm that the API works fine. At least if you post screenshots of Postman client would be helpful. :)